# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GeneratedPluginRegistrant"

Tags: xcode, flutter

I'm developing a Flutter app and getting this error. I have tried `flutter clean`, `rm podfile`, `pod deintegrate`, removed podfile.lock, but non seem to fix.

The full error message in Xcode is as follows:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "*OBJC_CLASS*$_GeneratedPluginRegistrant", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dumped the whole ios file and re-created it using `flutter create .` at the project directory level.  I just dragged the "ios" folder to the trash, then ran the command above at the command line.  I am guessing there was a file somewhere with an incorrect package name since I changed my package name to remove the "example" within the "com.example.".  Note to self: choose one project name and leave it as is!